# Making phone calls on Mac through a connected iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone

I'm looking for a client (for mac) that will help me make calls through a connected iPhone.
Anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.
You could try [BluePhoneElite 2](http://mirasoftware.com/BPE2/).

From the authors site:

> - Use your computer's microphone and speakers like a Bluetooth hands-free device!
> - Phone to computer call-log synchronization
> - Incoming call notification with caller ID and customizable alerts
> - On-screen call controls and duration tracking
> - Search and export call details with notes

and much more...